# building a FOR loop with several IF's and causing it to stop only in some runs

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a 2D array which some of it's members are numbers (playerID -1,2,3,4 etc.)and the rest are zeros.

I want to make a for loop containing all kinds of check methods that goes through the the loop and returns an answer. the checks are ranked, so that when one of the higher checks is returned TRUE, the loop for that playerID can terminate. Later on I want to use the check results to compare between the players, but first thing's first - I can't get the big FOR loop running.

I had in mind something like this:

```
for (int playerID = 1; playerID <= participants; playerID++)
{
    checkA = Check4forsequenceof4(matrix); //method A
    if (checkA == 0)
        continue;
    else
        Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check A");
        break;
    if (checkB == 0)
       continue;
    else
        Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check B");
        break;
    if (checkC == 0)
       continue;
    else
        Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check C");
        break;
}
```

Problems are: the break breaks out of the FOR loop instead of only from the if, and I can't think of how to check for the next playerID, and also can't figure out how best to store the results for every player for later display.

Comment: I think it burned out my retinas... :-) Not used to seeing that many continue and break in one loop...

Comment: `break` will not terminate an `if` as you've noticed.  You might try  putting the checks inside another loop "nested" inside the player loop.

Comment: What is the `break;` supposed to do?

Comment: `break` exits a loop or switch case. `continue` skips to the next loop iteration. In the context of your 'big loop', `break` will exit it and `continue` will skip to the next player. It's not clear what you are trying to do exactly. You may want to clarify that so we can better advise you.

Comment: You might also consider passing the player id to your check routines as a parameter.  It will make it easier to store information on a per-player basis.  (Hint: to do this, you will need something that stores a "collection" of values rather than just a single one.  It looks like you're already using such a structure...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, if you want to make this work, you can't rely on indentation - you need braces:

```
        if (checkA == 0)
            continue;
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check A");
            break;
        }
```

This will solve your immediate problem of the loop immediately breaking out.

That being said, given the above check, you'll NEVER check for B.  I suspect you want to invert your logic, as such:

```
        if (checkA != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check A");
            break;
        }
```

This will cause checkA to run, then checkB, etc.

Comment: thanks. I'm moving from python to C# and vice-versa and apparently am getting both mixed up

Answer (score 1):

You have a much bigger problem. Your code reads:

```
        checkA = Check4forsequenceof4(matrix); //method A
        if (checkA == 0)
            continue;
        else
            Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check A");
            break;
```

That will *always* break out of the loop the first time `checkA` is not 0. So `checkB` will never be executed.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The indentation of your code indicates that the `break` isn't necessary anywhere, since the default is tao fall through (which I think is what you want to do).

Comment: thanks. I'm moving from python to C# and vice versa and apperently am getting both mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allPlayers = new List<Player>();
// Fill the list allPlayers here.

var validPlayers = new List<Player>();
foreach (Player p in allPlayers) {
   if(CheckA(p) || CheckB(p) || CheckC(p)) {
       validPlayers.Add(p);
   }
}
```

Note: c# performs a so called shortcircuit evaluation. I.e. if CheckA returns true the others will not be evaluated any more. If CheckB returns true, then CheckC will not be evaluated. By the way "||" is a logical OR. If all checks have to be OK then use the logical AND "&&" instead. Here c# will stop checking as soon as a check fails.

If you are only interested in which check has returned true first, then only use "continue" when the check is OK, but no "break" otherwise.

My answer might not be very appropriate, but I am not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but as you saw I'm only a beginner - half of the elements in your answer are a bit like jibberish for me at the moment (but I understood the OR :) ). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.  Though I don't know when checkB or C is supposed to be set.   After the checkA check?

```
for (int playerID = 1; playerID <= participants; playerID++)
{
    checkA = Check4forsequenceof4(matrix); //method A
    if (checkA == 0)
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check A");

    if (checkB == 0)
        continue;
    Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check B");

    if (checkC == 0)
            continue;
    Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check C");
}
```

Comment: Yes, after A and B. I think this is what I was after, but I have to check. Thanks.

Comment: @jonatr: Hmm...I don't know. This will terminate the loop upon first encountering a check that returns `false`. Maybe that is what you want, but that's not what you said in the question.

Comment: Eh? It doesn't terminate the loop.  It skips to the next iteration.  He said "the break breaks out of the FOR loop instead of only from the if" so I removed them.

Answer (score 0):

unless I misunderstand your question:

```
for (int playerID = 1; playerID <= participants; playerID++)
        {
            checkA = Check4forsequenceof4(matrix); //method A
            if (checkA != 0)
                 Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check A");
            else
                 continue;

            if (checkB != 0)
               Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check B");
             else
                 continue;

            if (checkC != 0)
               Console.WriteLine(p + "completed check C");
             else
                 continue;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your if statements...

```
if (0 != checkValue) {
  Console.WriteLine(p + " completed check X");
  Continue;
}
```

So this will cause the loop to go into the next iteration when a check value is non-zero.

There is no such thing as breaking out of an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following code.

```
// This store all of the checks formed as Fun<Player, bool> delegates.
var checks = new List<Func<Player, bool>>();

checks.Add(x => DoesPlayerSatisfyCheck1(x));
checks.Add(x => DoesPlayerSatisfyCheck2(x));
checks.Add(x => DoesPlayerSatisfyCheck3(x));
// Add more checks here if necessary.

// This stores all players who have passed a check.
// The first check that passed will be associated with that player.
var results = new Dictionary<Player, int>();

// Loop through all players.
foreach (Player p in participants)
{
  // Now perform each test in order.
  for (int i = 0; i < checks.Count; i++)
  {
    Func<Player, bool> checker = checks[i];
    if (checker(p))
    {
      results.Add(p, i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

After this code executes the `results` data structure will contain an entry for each `Player` that passed one of the checks. That entry will also contain the check number. If you want to add more checks later you can simply add it to the `checks` data structure.

*This code does not behave the same as what you posted. But, it does behave per the requirement you gave; as best I can tell anyway.*